# gatsby in s3 subfolder not finding webpack and other js resources even with pathPrefix

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby

I have a gatsby site that works when I run it locally. It calls out to an api on another site.
When I deploy into a subfolder in s3, it looks for webpack and other .js resources in the root of the bucket and not the subfolder where the files are. How can I make the index.html in the subfolder see the webpack files?
I tried using `pathPrefix` and `gatsby build --prefix-paths`
It always looks for the files in the root of the bucket when I deploy and I see errors like this;
`app-898d909668879f4bfc6a.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Below is the code from index.js I added to the hello world sample from gatsby's site.

```
const IndexPage = () => {

const [Listing, setListing] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://clearlightdoor.com/cardsdict/7`);
      const json = await response.json();
      setListing(json);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <main style={pageStyles}>
      <h1 style={headingStyles}>
        Congratulations
        <br />
        <span style={headingAccentStyles}>— you just made a Gatsby site! </span>
      </h1>
    <div>
      {/* {JSON.stringify(Listing)} */}
      12345
    {Listing.map(item => (
          <li>Name: {item.card_name}, Text: {item.card_text} <img src={item.card_url}></img></li>
        ))}
    </div>
```

gatsby-confg.js

````
/**
 * @type {import('gatsby').GatsbyConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `reflectionsjs`,
    pathPrefix: `/reflections`,
    siteUrl: `https://tarot.clearlightdoor.com/reflections`,
  },
  plugins: [],
}
module.exports = {
 
}```
````

Comment: did you try the `gatsby-plugin-s3` https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/deploying-to-s3-cloudfront/#setting-up-s3 ?

Comment: I didn't see config for how to put the site in a subfolder although that will put one in the root.

Comment: did you check here? https://github.com/gatsby-uc/gatsby-plugin-s3?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration

Comment: What do ya know... right in the docs; "bucketPrefix" Thanks Yuri G.

Comment: I've never tried it, let me know if it works